# Web service request formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iOS app, where I need to request an url with email id. I have got the service api detail as below.

curl -X POST -c cookies.txt  https://www.mysamplewebserver.com:6554/shareme/api/v1/user/password/forgot
Request: { "emailId": "me@myserver.com" }

I don't get how to make this request. I should make it like that ->

```
https://www.mysamplewebserver.com:6554/shareme/api/v1/user/password/forgot/emailId=%@
or 
https://www.mysamplewebserver.com:6554/shareme/api/v1/user/password/forgot?emailId=%@
```

If anyone please help me getting a pseudo, so I can format the request according to that?

Thank you.

Comment: Neither. It's an HTTP POST, so you have to set the parameter `emailid` in the POST body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *email = @"test@test.com";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.mysamplewebserver.com:6554/shareme/api/v1/user/password/forgot/emailId=%@",email];
```

Hope that helps.